# submit button not working after validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

After entering the login details that is email and password, the form gets validated but it does not submit to next page? I have used two classes with form-control to give the text box red colour when no character is entered and green colour for success.

```js
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>User Login</h2>
        </div>
        <form class="form" id="form" action="success.html" method="post">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="user@gmail.com" id="email">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <button type="Submit" id="myBtn">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
</body>
```

This code snippet below is javascript for my login page

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var password = document.getElementById('password');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {

  var emailValue = email.value.trim();
  var passwordValue = password.value.trim();

  if (emailValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(email, 'Email cannot be blank');


  } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
    setErrorFor(email, 'Email is not valid');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(email);

  }

  if (passwordValue === '') {
    setErrorFor(password, 'Password cannot be blank');

  } else {
    setSuccessFor(password);

  }
  return true;
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
  var formControl = input.parentElement; //.form-control
  var small = formControl.querySelector('small');

  //add error message inside small
  small.innerText = message;

  //add error class
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';

}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
  var formControl = input.parentElement; //.form-control
  var small = formControl.querySelector('small');


  formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}

function isEmail(email) {
  return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0- 
  9] {
  1,
  3
}\.[0 - 9] {
  1,
  3
}\]) | (([a - zA - Z\ - 0 - 9] + \.) + [a - zA - Z] {
2,
})) $ / .test(email);
}
```

Comment: where should I return true .can you please help with adding return true to the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `submit` event listener, you are preventing the default behavior of the form which stops the form from getting submitted. You can simply add another check on the `checkInputs()` function:

```js
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (checkInputs()) {
            //If the form is valid, then submit it.
            form.submit()
        }
    });
```

If the form `checkInputs()` function returns true, then the form will be submitted. You can also write it like:

```js
if(checkInputs() === true){
  form.submit()
}
```

Comment: You are welcome @ara, you can do the upvote if it helped you :)